# How often to put water in coolant

Tags: coolant, coolant-leak, coolant-reservoir

Is it ok to put water in coolant? I live in a tropical country in Burma and i wonder if its ok to put water in a coolant? Also my coolant water fluid does drain every week. Is my coolant functioning well? How often to fill out water in coolant? Thanks

Comment: Related: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/3572/running-with-straight-water-as-coolant-in-the-summer-is-it-fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, if your coolant is draining every week, then you have a major leak somewhere, and I'd recommend you get that fixed first - otherwise you may find that you run out during a journey and overheat your engine, which could result in total engine failure.

Secondly, I would not recommend putting ordinary water directly in the coolant system for any length of time - it is better to use the recommended mixture of coolant and water - the coolant has a variety of additives etc in it that help to prevent the system from corroding.

Comment: So how often does a coolant last for hot temperatures? 2 weeks? A month?

Comment: Don't overlook the answer that suggests you have a problem with your cooling system. The weather and temperature have little impact on the life of the coolant, especially on the level in the system. If your system is losing coolant, it should be repaired. A quick check suggests that your coolant is good for 50,000 to 100,000 kilometers!

Comment: @fred_dot_u In Toyota Prius, the engine coolant is first changed at 150 000 km, and the inverter coolant at 240 000 km. Then afterwards the replacement interval is 90 000 km. So it may last even more!

Comment: coolant will literally "last" for years, unless you have a leak, or are significantly overheating. Your hot climate doesn't matter, if you are loosing fluid you have a problem that needs to be fixed.